# Issues installing angular-google-maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, bower

When installing angular-google-maps my whole site breaks and I get errors from http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/nomod?p0=ngTable

The 2 main errors say

1. Cannot read property 'OverlayView' of undefined
2. Module ngTable is not available ....

This happens as soon as I install the framework without me doing anything else, the command I run is

```
bower install angular-google-maps --save
```

This is the first thing I've ever installed with bower on my own so there might be something I am not doing.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure that *bower requires Node, npm and Git*.

Remember, bower is command line utility and if you are installing package like this then it is going to install that package at project level.

And for its installation you need to get in the command line mode, *switch to the project root folder* and type the following command at the command line prompt:

```
                          bower install "Package-Name"
```

In your case it will be bower install angular-google-maps --save

And moreover it you want to install this package globally then add "-g" with above bower command.

For further info you can refer this link:

[Installing and removing bower package](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/installing-and-removing-bower-packages.html)